# Access WebHostBuilder's host with WebClient gets rejected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to access a controller's route which is hosted using this code:

```
var configuration =
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["urls"] = url
                })
                .Build();

        var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHost(webHost =>
            {
                webHost.UseConfiguration(configuration);
                webHost.UseUrls(url);
                webHost.UseTestServer();
                webHost.UseStartup<TestStartup>();

            });

        var host = await hostBuilder.StartAsync();
```

While accessing it with

```
 var client = host.GetTestClient();
 var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/test/testdata");
```

works fine I'll get a WebException saying 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it' when I try to access it using a WebClient

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var response = webClient.DownloadString(url + "api/v1/test/validData");
```

I'm not sure if setting the url actually works (that's why I got multiple test code in the configuration) but using the hosts baseaddress returns the same result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetTestClient` returns a HttpClient, that uses a [special `HttpMessageHandler`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.3/src/Hosting/TestHost/src/ClientHandler.cs) that dispatches the request directly into the ASP.NET Core server pipeline. This specialized code avoids sending actual data over the network by orchestrating the application code directly.

This allows doing efficient integration tests that will test all of your application code set up properly. But since this will emulate network traffic without opening actual sockets, you will not be able to use this for end-to-end tests with foreign clients.

So since `WebClient` does not support message handlers, you will not be able to use it for integration tests. You will have to use the `HttpClient` the test server gives you.